# Does switchmap automatically calls the subscription?

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to obtain a behavior such that if current observable is changed in value, the respective observables linked should be invoked respectively.

The following code works as intended, but I just need some conformation regarding this behavior, I am trying to implement this on production site.

I know switchMap unsubscribes from current subscription and resubscribes to new one that's returned.
But, Does it also call the new observable subscribed to kick in and run the code it has or is this run by the pipe operator or am I missing any crucial concept ?

Can some one kindly, clarify this.
Thank you.

Here is the stackblitz code link ::: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ktnf9x  :: and Overview

```
let a = new BehaviorSubject(null);
let b = new BehaviorSubject(null);
let c = new BehaviorSubject(null);
let d = new BehaviorSubject(null);

let a$ = a.asObservable();
let b$ = b.asObservable();
let c$ = c.asObservable();
let d$ = d.asObservable();


  d$
    .pipe(
      switchMap(
        data => {
          console.log("from d :: " + data);
          return c$;
        }
      )
    )
    .pipe(
      switchMap(
        data => {
          console.log("from c :: " + data);
          return b$;
        }
      )
    )
    .pipe(
      switchMap(
        data => {
          console.log("from b :: " + data);
          return a$;
        }
      )
    )
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("from a :: " + data);
        console.log(""); // for next line.
      }
    )



  b.next("calls");
  a.next("allSubs");

  c.next("it");
  d.next("does");

  d.next('yes');
```

finally --> Outputs ::: yes it calls allSubs

Comment: the stament is wrong switchman alters the timeline you can say. but no it doesn't subscribe or unsubscribe

Comment: hm, as per this website  https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html 
******
The main difference between switchMap and other flattening operators is the cancelling effect. On each emission the previous inner observable (the result of the function you supplied) is cancelled and the new observable is subscribed. You can remember this by the phrase switch to a new observable.  ******

Comment: it says switches to a new observable don't see anything about subscribes

Comment: I don't even understand what are you really asking but I removed the pipes for you and format a bit. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bmpbma)

Comment: thank you, for the reply, but in stackblitz [ new link :: stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-uk8q3e ] initially I didn't emitted any new c value, it was initiated with null in behavior subject.. Yet when ever I emit something to d, other values like c, b, a are triggered emitting null. So wondering. if switchmap triggers the c$ subscription though nothing is emitted from c. or b or a. or is it from pipe. is the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it simpler to explain. SwitchMap unsubscribe c$ when d$ emits. if d emit once and c keeps emitting you will get a sequence of d-c-c-c
if d emits again in the middle you will get d-c-c-c-d-c-c-c

```
 d$
    .pipe(
      switchMap(
        data => {
          console.log("from d :: " + data);
          return c$;
        }
      )
    )
```

Comment: thank you, for the reply, but in stackblitz [ new link :: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-uk8q3e ] initially I didn't emitted any new c value, it was initiated with null in behavior subject.. Yet when ever I emit something to d, other values like c, b, a are triggered emitting null. So wondering. if switchmap triggers the c$ subscription though nothing is emitted from c. or b or a. or is it from pipe.

Comment: that because you are using behaviorsubject and it always emit the initial value first when you subscribe, if you change them to just plain subject things will start make sense.

Comment: Oh Perfect, Makes sense. Thank you. very much. !!